# How to count "data-price" attributes in div-boxes with Javascript in Html5 when something is dropped?

Tags: javascript, html, count

i want to sum up the sum of the numbers in the data attributes "data-price" of my div boxes via javascript and display the result in a div box too.

The problem I have is, that i got the following java-script, but it counts only the value of inputs instead of the "data-price"-attributes of my div boxes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
var tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
}
document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
</script>
```

My div boxes:

```
<div name="qty" data-price="1.12" dragable="true">Text</div>
```

Output div box:

```
<div id="total">0</div>
```

What do i have to change?

Comment: `java` is **not** the same as `javascript`!!

Comment: Seems like you're asking how to `access data attribute in html5`, so maybe you should try [**searching the web**](https://www.google.com/search?q=access+data+attribute+in+html5), and you will learn how.

Comment: I want the script to sum  up the numbers of all data attributes "data-price".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the following:

```
if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
```

you are attempting to access the *value* property of elements that do not have a default HTML *value* attribute. You seem to want to access *data-price* (not value) attribute, which is a [*data-** attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). Also, you have floats, not ints, so use:

```
if (parseFloat(arr[i].dataset.price))
```

e.g.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var total = 0;
  var nodes = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  [].forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
    console.log(node.dataset.price);
    total += parseFloat(node.dataset.price)
  })
  console.log('Total: ' + total);
}
```

```html
<div name="qty" data-price="1.12" dragable="true">This one costs 1.12</div>
<div name="qty" data-price="1.45" dragable="true">This one costs 1.45</div>
```

There are many questions and answers here about [*displaying values as currency*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+numbers+as+currency).

Comment: Can I it also display two decimalnumbers?